# How can I send text to text editor with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, forms, selenium, xpath

I want to send a text to the post editor with Selenium, but I have a problem with xpaths, how can I solve it?

**Error code:**

> DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please
> use find_element() instead   element
> = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").send_keys(DETAIL)

**My Code**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").send_keys(DETAIL)
```

**The part where I want to send the text**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").send_keys(DETAIL)
```

should be due to depreciate also import by.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr").send_keys(DETAIL)
```

You also have an iframe so switch to that first.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset")))
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: but i wrote it in python

Comment: This is python.

Comment: The problem still continues

Comment: Can you post the html element for the iframe. I need the css selector for it plus whaetever input element the send key is to.

Comment: #cke_1_contents > iframe

Comment: so I would recommend a unique identifier for the body css selector

Comment: The css selector didn't work either

Comment: Can you post the url or is it private

Comment: Try this for the send keys.

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr").send_keys(DETAIL)`

Comment: I tried this it didn't work

Comment: Did it not send or not find

Comment: Error code : Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Can't really test since cloudfare.